# Как вызвать BSOD в C#?

Tags: c#

Все привет. Ребята, помогите, пожалуйста, вызвать BSOD на C#. =)

Один способ пробовал: убить csrss.exe... но убивается он только из админ. режима, а надо ещё и из user-mode. Может кто-то подскажет, как это с делать с помощью неуправляемого кода?

Заранее очень благодарен!

P.S Нет! Я не вирус пишу. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приложение, выполняемое в пользовательском режиме (а именно в этом режиме выполняются любые приложения на C#), не может вызвать BSOD. Чтобы получить BSOD нужно

1. написать приложение, которое будет выполняться в режиме ядра, например, драйвер;
2. внести в код драйвера ошибку, которая будет вызвать BSOD, например, деление на ноль;
3. из приложения на C# обратиться к драйверу и вызвать исполнение ошибочного кода.

Код драйвера можно взять из шаблонов WDK/KMDF. Обращаться через WinAPI. Еще есть шанс, что как-то можно сломать стандартные драйвера, например, COM-портов.

Comment: Писать ошибочный код не обязательно. Вполне допустимо вызвать из драйвера ф-цию <a href=http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/kmarch/k105_8omq.htm>KeBugCheck</a>. Затем можно в драйвере это повесить на определенный IOCTL, и вызывать его из user-mode app.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону API функции `RtlSetProcessIsCritical`. При помощи нее можно пометить свой процесс как критичный, что возможно приведет к BSOD при его закрытии.

На CodeProject есть небольшой [пример](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/RtlSetProcessIsCritical.aspx), но на C++.

Comment: Еще раз - завершение критического системного процесса НЕ ГАРАНТИРУЕТ BSOD! <a href=http://www.jeffwu.net/?p=56>Пруф</a> Ни минусовать, ни плюсовать не буду.

Comment: Поправил